# Correcting data v Manipulating Query to accommodate data discrepancy?

Tags: sql-server

I hope this is not the wrong place to ask, if so, please kindly advice the right place.

Say in a company you have 2 database that are different yet contains the same data. While how the data stored is generally the same, it has quite a lot small data inconsistency and discrepancy. But you are given a task to collect data from those two databases.
I wanted to know how would a DBA handle this situation, given that you cannot fiddle directly to the actual data without getting permissions from involved departments.

Will they, say :
1. Create a temporary DB to accommodate things.
2. Adjust the Query to accommodate for all kinds of problem that can be traced
or maybe there are other solutions?

Thanks before.

Comment: What sort of inconsistencies and discrepancies are you talking about?

Comment: For example for the same type of data (say customer billing data), in database A the transaction type is X , but in database B the transaction type is empty. From a hindsight the description column seems viable to help sort this out, but the problem is sometimes the description left out the important words. That's just one example, say that there are more than one case which is lurking and not obvious.